Spin operator acting on meson field operator
In the book "Heavy Quark physics" of Manohar/Wise in chapter 2.5 the meson field operator in the ground state configuration with one heavy and one light quark has been derived. The field operator has the form
$H_{v_r}^{(Q)} =\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & i P_{v_r}^{(Q)}-i \vec{\sigma} \vec{P_{v_r}}^{* (Q) }\\
    0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$
for $v_r=(1,\vec{0})$.
Next in the book is written that the field transforms as a (1/2,1/2) representation under $S_Q \times S_l$. To rotate the field one needs the commutator of the spin generators with the field operator.
My question is how can I obtain the commutator relation
$[ S_{Q,i}, H_{v_r}^Q ]= \frac{i}{8} \epsilon_{ijk}  [\gamma^j, \gamma^k] H_{v_r}^{(Q)} $
?
Since the first index of the heavy meson field denotes the heavy quark configuration and the second index denotes the light quark configurations but the spin operator is only acting on the heavy quark part of the meson field or better saying on the first spinor index regarding the matrix components.
